# Consume Result of .NET Function Returning object for a class in Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have function like this in .NET

```
Public Class P
    Public Function GetObjectForMyClass(ByVal _MyClass As MyClass) As MyClass
        _MyClass.Name="Mahi New"
        Return _MyClass
    End Function
End Class
```

Now we have the following Classic ASP Page:

```
<%
Dim P
Dim MyClass 
Set P = Server.CreateObject("Project.Assembly.Namespace.P")
Set MyClass = Server.CreateObject("Project.Assembly.Namespace.MyClass")
MyClass.Name="Mahi"

MyClass= P.GetObjectForMyClass(MyClass)
...
...
...
%>
```

this giving error like this:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument: 'GetObjectForMyClass'

Comment: What happens when you change the return value of `GetObjectForMyClass` to basic type like string? Does it work well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing a COM interface on the livrary?

If not, to expose a COM Interface from a .NET Type Library so it can be called from a classic ASP page we need to:

1. Ensure assembly GUID is assigned, e.g:
   `[assembly: Guid("dde7717b-2b75-4972-a4eb-b3d040c0a182")]`
2. Ensure COMVisible attribute is True –
   `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`
3. Check the project option “Register for COM interop”
4. Put a GUID attribute on the class, e.g.
   [GuidAttribute("4df74b15-d531-4217-af7e-56972e393904")]
5. Ensure you have the namespace declaration in your code:
   `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`
6. Register using Regasm.exe

**EDIT**
Given that you have exposed the COM interface, have you tried the following (using `set`):

```
set MyClass= P.GetObjectForMyClass(MyClass)
```

Comment: Thanks James. Yes i did above things,and  if i simply call like this P.GetObjectForMyClass(MyClass)
Response.Write(MyClass.Name) then it is giving the result like this "Mahi New" so it is calling the function,no problem in calling the function but it is giving error while Setting it to the object (like this: MyClass= P.GetObjectForMyClass(MyClass)).But i want it to set to the object.

Comment: James I tried above solution also but it is giving same exception.